# Code works, but RSpec test fails. "expected nil to be an instance of String"

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm using Ruby and RSpec.
I've written some code that reads a number of ascii pics from a file and presents the correct picture based on i. The code works:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :pics

  def initialize
    @pics = get_frames
  end

  def draw_pic
    pics[i]
  end

  def get_frames
    frames = Dir.glob("ascii_frames/*").sort
    frames.map do |ascii| 
      open(ascii) do |file|
        file.read
      end
    end
  end
end
```

HOWEVER, the RSpec test doesn't.

```
# test_spec.rb

require_relative 'spec_helper.rb'

describe MyClass do
  before :each do
    @my_class = MyClass.new
  end

  describe "#draw_pic" do
    it "returns a string" do
      @my_class.draw_pic.should be_an_instance_of String
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the test_spec, I get the error "expected nil to be an instance of String". My other test examples work fine, and when I write draw_pic.class I get the expected String.

Any insights as to why the RSpec test fails?

Comment: And where is `draw_gallow` method implemented?

Comment: Sorry, changed the names when posting the question, forgot to change all of them. Fixed in edit now.

Comment: You probably missed `@` before `pics` in `draw_pic` method. ANyway - what is `i`?

Comment: @BroiSatse why? There's `attr_accessor :pics`, so no difference.

Comment: @MarekLipka - ah, missed that line. :) Still, no `i` method or variable.

Comment: What happens if you use absolute path in `MyClass#get_frames`?

Comment: @MarekLipka - No difference

Comment: @BroiSatse - It's from a Hangman game, so i is the calculated value of the number of guesses left.

Comment: @user2765142 - I do understand what it is to represent, however it is neither defined in the class nor passed as an argument, hence your code in the form you posted will throw `undefined method or variable` exception. Since however it is just a snippet of your real code, it is not really so important.

Comment: @BroiSatse - Ok! I figured it was better not to post all the code, since it's quite a lot. Would you like me to post a bigger snippet anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
def draw_pic
  pics[i]
end
```

what is **i**? Any way, check if

```
Dir.glob("ascii_frames/*").sort
```

is executed in dir you expect it to. It just looks like @pics is empty, or does not have needed element. You can use some debug output to figure out what exactly is happening

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :pics

  def initialize
    @pics = get_frames
    puts "@pics = #{@pics}"
  end

  def draw_pic
    pics[i]
  end

  def get_frames
    frames = Dir.glob("ascii_frames/*").sort
    puts "frames = #{frames}"
    frames.map do |ascii| 
      open(ascii) do |file|
        file.read
      end
    end
  end
end
```

just run specs and see what is written. Any way, I'm surprised you don't get undefined local variable exception

Comment: I've truncated the original code, which is contained in four files. It's a complete Hangman game, and the code works fine, the frames are read properly and displayed correctly. What I can't figure out is why the RSpec test file doesn't work.

Comment: the spec seems correct, so I suggest you add some more specs - for instance, @my_class.pics.should_not be_empty

Comment: "@my_class.pics.should_not be_empty" fails, too. "undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass" So far so good, for some reason it's empty, but still works. I figure there must be something wrong with the loadpath, since the test file execute from a different directory than the main file.

Comment: now it seems strange - if it was empty, you would get `expected empty? to return false, got true`, but it is nil

Comment: Ya, I'm pretty bewildered, too. I will keep trying to get this to work. Thank you for taking your time and trying to help me!